# Scala - If expressions

Tags: scala, if-statement

I am completely new to Scala. I try to implement the if-expression example on p. 160 from the "Scala Programming" book of Odersky, Spoon, Venners (see [here](http://ccfit.nsu.ru/~den/Scala/programming_in_scala_2nd.pdf)).

```
var filename = "default.txt"
if(!args.isEmpty) 
  filename = args(0)
```

Why is this code not compiled? How can I make it run?

Comment: Well, what error are you getting, and also did you declare the `args` variable somewhere?

Comment: Hi! What kind of error do you get? Did you wrap it to `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {...}` before running. Do you use scalac or scala REPL?

Comment: can you post the error you get?

Comment: 1) The compiler usually gives you a hint if the program is not compilable. What does it say? Looks like a valid program to me, even though obviously nonsensical (must crash with ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception).

2) You forgot the negation '!'.

Comment: I use IntelliJ (without REPL Mode): The error says: "Error (1, 104) not found: value args ...". So, do I then have to specify an "args"-object first?

Comment: Then you should probably create a variable called `args` somewhere. The error tells you exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In "Write some Scala scripts" on page 75, it says:

> Command line arguments to a Scala script are available 
>   via a Scala array named `args`.

The code snippets in the book are expected to be run as separate little scripts, that is, you are supposed to save the code in a text file, for example called `if.scala`, and then execute it with `scala if.scala`. When the code is run as a script, the variable `args` of type `Array[String]` is automatically brought into scope, and contains the command line arguments passed to your program, that is, if you invoke it like this:

```
scala if.scala "a" "b" "c"
```

the array `Array("a", "b", "c")` will be available as `args` in your code.

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception occurs because you forgot the negation '!'.

By the way: what you have here, is rather an `if`-statement. An `if`-expression is something like

```
if (args.isEmpty) "default.txt" else args(0)
```

but they probably say that in the book somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have access to the `args` value, probably because you need to wrap this code into a `main` function (or whatever the name you want, but I guess this is the case), which is commonly done like:

```
object YourProgram {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var filename = "default.txt"

    if(!args.isEmpty) 
      filename = args(0)
  }
}
```

Then, if you are using the Scala REPL, you can paste that code and try:

```
scala> YourProgram.main(Array("myText.txt"))
```

**UPDATE:**

As Andrey pointed out, the snippets from the book are intended to be run as separate scripts, so if for example you have the following program: `if (args.isEmpty) println("no args") else println("args")` in a `script.scala` file, you can get on the console the expected behavior:

```
$ scala script.scala 
no args
$ scala script.scala 1 2
args
```

Answer (score 0):

From page 160 of the book you posted:

> This code declares a variable, filename, and initializes it to a
>   default value. ***It then uses an if expression to check whether any
>   arguments were supplied to the program***. If so, it changes the variable
>   to hold the value specified in the argument list. If no arguments were
>   supplied, it leaves the variable set to the default value

This `if` statement is only a fraction of the code, given as an example. You need to define `args` (which is the name given to the array of arguments supplied to the program with its run command).